# How to send form details to database and send email with form details CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

This is my code after a form has been submitted. I have succeeded in making the values display on the page but then I would like these same values to be inserted into the database and at the same time they are sent as email to the user and admin email. The user's email if part of the form `$_POST` values. I would like to later extract and update the values. That is not a problem. The problem is achieving save to database, email client and admin and save to database at the same time or one after the other.

NB: I am using API to convert some of the values there directly before display so doing it in a controller or model may save the original value instead of the converted one which is not desired. Unless there is a better way to do that. I'm using CodeIgniter 3.

Please help me out. Thank you. Code Below:

```
<?php
    function generateRandomString($length = 26) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString; 
    }
?>

<?php
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $txn_ref = strtoupper(generateRandomString());
    $txn_status = "Pending";
    $exc_from = $_POST['exc_from'];
    $exc_to = $_POST['exc_to'];
    $from_amount = $_POST['from_amount'];
    $to_amount = $_POST['to_amount'];
    $account = $_POST['account'];
?>

<div class="row">
<h3>Your <?php echo $exc_from ?> to <?php echo $exc_to ?> Transaction Details</h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Payment ID</th>
      <td><?php echo $txn_ref ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <td><?php echo $email ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <td><?php echo $username ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>You Give</th>
      <td><?php echo $from_amount ?> <?php echo $exc_from ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>You Get</th>
      <td><?php echo $to_amount ?> <?php echo $exc_to ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Your <?php echo $exc_to ?> Wallet</th>
      <td><?php echo $account ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Transaction Status</th>
      <td><?php echo $txn_status ?></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Make Payment to</th>
      <td><?php echo $ouraccount; ?></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>View in Dashboard</th>
      <td><a href="<?=base_url()?>transaction/<?php echo $txn_ref ?>">View Transaction</a><br></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should try using the form validation library, because then you will have access to all of the values quite easily.

Comment: @BrianGottier Can you please give an more insight into this? I can get the values quite easily but then, I wanted to store in the database and send it to email Now I achieved sending to the database. I added $params as a variable and linked to the database and I used   `    $this->db->insert('transactions',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
 ?>` beneath the code.

Comment: That being the case, all you need is to follow directions: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: @BrianGottier thanks. You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer to my question, I worked around a bit and figured out what worked for me. Maybe it could help you out. I'm opened to editing since I'm not too sure if I followed the best practices but most of the best practices I followed were not giving the desired results. Everything went into the same file in this order.

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 26) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
$randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString; }?>

<?php
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$txn_ref = strtoupper(generateRandomString());
$txn_status = "Pending";
$exc_from = $_POST['exc_from'];
$exc_to = $_POST['exc_to'];
$from_amount = $_POST['from_amount'];
$to_amount = $_POST['to_amount'];
$account = $_POST['account'];

?>
```

Display On Page

```
 <!-- Display Values -->
   <div class="row">
    <h3>Your <?php echo $exc_from ?> to <?php echo $exc_to ?> Details</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Payment ID</th>
      <td><?php echo $txn_ref ?></td>
      </tr>
      ...
         <th>View in Dashboard</th>
      <td><a href="<?=base_url()?>transaction/<?php echo $txn_ref ?>">View 
  Transaction</a><br></td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Insert Into Database

```
    <?php
  //Insert into Database

 $params = array(
'user_id' => $user_id ,
'email' => $email ,
'username' => $username ,
'txn_ref' => $txn_ref ,
'txn_status' => $txn_status ,
'exc_to' => $exc_to ,
'exc_from' => $exc_from ,
'from_amount' => $from_amount ,
'to_amount' => $to_amount ,
'account' => $account ,
);

$this->db->insert('transactions',$params);
return $this->db->insert_id();
?>
```

Send Email

```
<?php
 //Send as Email
$m_user_id = $user_id;
$m_email = $email;
$m_username = $username;
$m_txn_ref = $txn_ref;
$m_exc_to = $exc_to;
$m_exc_from = $exc_from;
$m_from_amount = $from_amount;
$m_to_amount = $to_amount;
$m_account = $account;
$message = 'Message Here';

 $this->load->library('email');
 config['mailtype'] = 'html';

 $this->email->from('from@email.com', 'From');
 $this->email->to($m_email);
 $this->email->cc('cc@email.com');

 $this->email->subject('Email Test');
 $this->email->message($message);

 $this->email->send();
 if ($this->email->send(FALSE))
 {
    echo 'Mail was not sent';
 }

 ?>
```

I hope this helps